# Cannot protect a question if I edit it first

Tags: bug, protected-questions

If I edit a question, and then click "protect", the button in the confirmation dialog does nothing. I have to refresh the page to protect the question.

> [image: gif demonstrating the problem.]

I also noticed this bug a while ago. It started happening some time™ after the new confirmation box was introduced (the fancy one in the gif, not the plain one building on the standard browser UI).

Tested in FF 83.0 on Linux Mint. Also reproduced in the same browser with no plugins enabled.

Comment: Off-topic and sorry if I'm out of the loop but what does "™" imply here? I noticed it being used in a similar manner a few times on meta but I have no idea what it's supposed to mean besides its original meaning.

Comment: @41686d6564 "some time™" is likely a variant of "soon™" which means "not actually soon", the joke is that some companies say a feature/product is releasing "soon" but due to delays they end up repeating "its coming out soon" enough to trademark it. Though I think OP is just using the phrase to mean its just *unclear* when this started happening.